# How do I calculate the total space used in a program?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say I have created a program in C/C++ and have a source code.
I'd like to know the total memory during the program execution.

Someone has mentioned something about "malloc" and "hook" 
Is there any other way to trace the spaced used?

Comment: I would say "something about valgrind"

Comment: This will be platform-dependent.  What platform are you running on?

Comment: I believe, in general, this is an unsolvable problem. Unless the program is completely static (and if it is, why did you write it?) or very simple, the program footprint is liable to change from run to run.

Comment: @jpm Theoretically yes, but in practice you can always get a decent estimate.

Comment: Well, if we're talking about estimates, we could go all the way down to three categories: "a reasonable amount", "more than we can reasonably expect users to spare", and "holy crap, it's leaking all over the place!" :-)

Comment: @Pubby: actually what you can get is a decent estimate of the space complexity of a program. Otherwise even the simplest program can take up a lot of memory with a large enough input...

Comment: @jpm: actually, I have occasionally encountered a fourth category: "Why won't `ps` work?", otherwise known as "How do I kill this thing?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Linux or something Unix-based, you could most likely use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Valgrind runs the program and intercepts all of its memory allocations and prints the stats once it exits. It's a very useful tool for checking for memory leaks and memory usage. If you're running Windows, I haven't a clue.

Comment: In particular the valgrind tool "massif" is a heap profiler, which will show usage over the life of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor memory use with the "top" command in linux or taskmgr in windows.

Answer (score 0):

In linux-like systems, you can use info from

```
/proc/self
```

to find out total amount of memory used by your program during the runtime. It also contains many other info about the process, see

```
man 5 proc
```

for details.